# Lightning Application CSS rendered inline

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

For all lightning applications in my sandbox, I'm noticing all of the SLDS CSS is being rendered inside an inline `<style>` tag - over 4,000 lines of CSS inline. I would have expected the SLDS CSS to be part of app.css, not inline.

The problem is that since SLDS is being rendered inline, it takes precedence over component CSS which is not how this is supposed to work. Does anyone know why SLDS CSS would be rendered inline in my applications?

Points to note:

- This is happening only in sandboxes
- The page is served with the `<style>` tag and all the CSS rendered inline - so we can be sure there's no funny JavaScript dynamically injecting the `<style>` tag.
- The `<style>` tag is positioned just before `</head>`.

Don't know if this is normal behavior for custom lightning applications in sandboxes. I don't see this happening on my developer edition org OR production for this org.

EDIT:

Following is some code that I see in Page Source when my custom lightning applications are rendered:

```
<style>@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {font-family:'Salesforce Sans'; src:url(/_slds/fonts/v2.3.0/SalesforceSans-Light.woff2) format('woff2'),url(/_slds/fonts/v2.3.0/SalesforceSans-Light.woff) format('woff'); font-weight:300}
...
code, kbd, pre, samp {font-family:monospace,monospace; font-size:1em}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {color:inherit; font:inherit; margin:0}
...
.slds-action-overflow_touch__footer, .slds-action-overflow--touch__footer {position:relative; flex-shrink:0; border-top:1px solid rgb(217, 219, 221); padding:.75rem 1rem; background-color:rgb(249, 249, 250); box-shadow:0 -2px 4px #f9f9fa}
.slds-timeline__media, .slds-media_timeline, .slds-media--timeline {position:relative; padding-bottom:1.5rem}
...
/*over 4 thousand lines later*/
</style>
</head>
```

My understanding is that these 4k+ lines should have been part of app.css like they are on production and on my developer edition. I don't know why they're being rendered inline in the sandbox I'm working on.

EDIT 2:

I have the following CSS in my lightning component - which will be rendered as part of app.css:

```
.THIS .chevronup
{
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

This is being overridden by the following part of the inline CSS:

```
.slds-input-has-icon .slds-input__icon {
    ..
    margin-top: -.4375rem;
    ..
}
```

The element in question is a `<button>` with both `slds-input__icon` and `chevronup` classes on it. It gets a -16px margin-top on prod, but -.4375rem margin-top in sandbox.

On prod, the whole thing works fine because `.slds-input-has-icon .slds-input__icon` is part of app.css only and NOT rendered inline, and therefore the component CSS takes precedence

I can solve this thing by just doing !important on the component CSS but the reason I'm asking the question is this inline thing will mean that SLDS will ALWAYS have priority over component CSS by virtue of being rendered inline which is not how this is supposed to work.

Comment: I'll edit the post to add a code sample that describes what I'm seeing

Comment: @sfdcfox I added some more details to the question

Comment: Thanks, I already saw/understood that, but how does it relate to " it takes precedence over component CSS which is not how this is supposed to work"? What sort of behavior are you seeing because of this change?

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks a lot for your help - I have added even more details.